# Mongoengine updating embedded document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have the following code and i'm trying to update an embedded document in a listfield.

```
store = store_service.get_store_from_product_id(product_id)
got_product, idx = get_product_from_store(store, product_id)

product = Product()
product.pid = got_product.pid
product.display_name = display_name
product.description = description
product.rank = rank
product.price = price
product.categories = categories
product.properties = properties

store.catalog.products[idx] = product

print store.catalog.products[idx].__unicode__()

store.save()
```

When I print out my product, it has the correct values, but when I save it, its not persisting.  There are no errors being thrown.  Any thoughts one what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`store.catalog.products[idx] = product` can be applied  for `DictField()`. For `ListField()`. You can try:

```
store.catalog.products = [product]
```

or

```
store.catalog.products.append(product)
```

And you need to call save on the object:

```
store.save()
```

There is the possibility of `atomic updates` which can help in other cases:

```
Store.objects(id='123400000').update_one(push__catalog__products=product)
```